# Notation for Sum that is invariant to reordering

Tags: notation

Assume that we have to compute a sum of n objects: $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$$ How can we show mathematically that the labelling of the index does not matter? In other words, how can it be shown that the sum is invariant to the index labels?

In this case, labelling an index is assigning a number to each element in the set, such that each element is identified with a unique number.

Comment: What are you asking? Like showing that if $i$ is replaced with a different letter $j$ the sum is the same? Or are you trying to show that for any invertible function $f: \lbrace 1 ... n\rbrace \rightarrow \lbrace 1 ... n \rbrace $ that $S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{f(i)}$ is the same?

Comment: I guess what I mean to say is, can you define what it means to "label an index"

Comment: You mean like if we have $a_n = n$ and $S = \sum_{i=1}^{10} a_n$ then we could specify any random jumbling.  So, we could have $b_n = a_{n+2}, ~: ~1 \leq n \leq 8,~$ with $b_9 = a_1, b_{10} = a_2.$  Then, since $\sum_{n=1}^{10} b_n$ is summing the same terms as $\sum_{n=1}^{10}a_n$, you have that the two summations will result in the same tally.  Have I interpreted correctly what you are trying to ask?

Comment: This sort of proof will involve setting up "bookkeeping" to relate the possible re-indexed sums.  One approach is to consider them in terms of *permutations* of the indices.  You might think of another way, but you should look for ways to take advantage of the finiteness of the sum to enable mathematical induction.

Comment: Observe $x+y = y + x$ via commutativity. Induct. This will show any finite sum can be rearranged. If you then ask how to formally deal with the concept of indices, you probably need to state a logical framework in which to prove the result.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas the latter!

Comment: I edited title of your question as Sum being invariant to reordering seemed to be a better description for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $S_1,S_2$ where

$$S_1 =\sum_{x \in X}x ,S_2 =\sum_{x \in X}x$$
then
$S_1=S_2$

since no ordering of summation defined for either of $S_1,S_2$ the sum must be invariant to ordering.

Or if it is understood that sum is invariant to ordering then something like following example should do :

$$A={\{x | (\forall k \in \mathbb N)[x=\frac{1}{k^2}] \}} , S =\sum_{x\in A}x$$